# Connecting to external database using React, Nodejs, Express, and PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, ssh

I created a course management system using PHP and HTML. I use PostgreSQL to store data. I use my school's server and database where I could put my files on there with WinSCP and can connect to the database with putty via SSH where I can run queries. Everything works fine.

I am trying to do the exact same project using React, Nodejs, Express, and PostgreSQL. All the tutorials I see online show how to connect to a local database. I want to eventually publish this project and for it to communicate with the same database as my PHP project. Is that possible? So far, I was able to build the client-side of the application(react) but have not been able to communicate with the database (server-side). Any tips?

Comment: publish it where? If it's on the same network as your school's database server then it should be ok, unless there are firewalls rules on the machine itself which you might need to amend. If you deploy it on the same server that should be even less of an issue. But if you're talking about publishing it on the public internet then I would be very surprised if your school will open a port from outside into their server, which is what you'd need. _Maybe_ they would if it's restricted to connections from the specific IP of the server where your app's backend is deployed, but even then it's a risk.

Comment: Beyond that, `have not been able to` tells us nothing about what code you've written or what specific error or problem you've encountered (which might, along with the deployment information, give us a clue about the precise nature of what's blocking you).

Comment: yes, the public internet. It's not my school's database, it's more of a server one of my teachers created for us to play with. I want to publish it to add it to my personal project portfolio.

Comment: It may not be the school's database, but you said it's their server and therefore it's (presumably) on their private internal network (although I admit you didn't actually say that - is it actually in the cloud, perhaps?), which is the important point as regards access. If it doesn't need to be on the school's server, consider moving it to the same hosting environment where you plan to host the application.